# How to hide download file path from user using php?

Tags: php

When user want to download file from my web site, user have to click link like below

https://www.example.com/download.php?aaa=111&bbb=222

download.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$aaa = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[aaa]);
$bbb = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[bbb]);
if(($aaa = '111')&($bbb = '222'))  // this line is example for ask stackoverflow //
{
    $filePath_try_to_download = 'attachments_files/test.pdf';
    if(file_exists($filePath_try_to_download)) 
    {
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath_try_to_download);   
        $fileName = "test.pdf";     
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath_try_to_download);                   
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

I want to know when user download file from this link `https://www.example.com/download.php?aaa=111&bbb=222` user can get my file path on server or not (`attachments_files/test.pdf`). If user can get my file path, how can i hide it's ? (`file in this dir is very importance`)

Comment: What server are you using? Apache? You won't be able to do what you want with PHP, since PHP only runs the scripts - it doesn't handle the routing. **Also note that security through obfuscation is no security at all.**

Comment: @Matthew php can easily handle this and that too without any obfuscation

Comment: @Hannky Panky-- pdf is example

Comment: @Matthew Herbst - apache

Comment: Users wont see this path whats the question then?

Comment: Only your code sees that path

Comment: @Hanky Panky - could you please show me how to user see path ?

Comment: @HankyPanky my impression from the OP's question is that he wants to hide all files except one in the directory from being visible. Is that not your understanding of the question? If it is, how could this be done using PHP? PHP hosted via Apache has no capability (to my knowledge) to handle all HTTP requests directly.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst just put my observations in an answer. From what i could understand OP wants to provide a file for download to the visitors without revealing its actual location. So they want people to be able to download that file only when they reach a certain url with certain query string values and not with direct file name

Answer (score 2):

Since I was posting comments from my Phone, they couldn't really explain much, so here goes your answer.

> I want to know when user download file from this link https://www.example.com/download.php?aaa=111&bbb=222 user can get my file path on server or not (attachments_files/test.pdf).

**No**, Users can not see that file path which you are reading via `readfile()`. They will not be able to find out that file's location at all.

And if you want to eliminate any chances of people guessing the file path simply put those files outside of your web root folder and then `readfile()` them from there.

```
$filePath_try_to_download = 'attachments_files/test.pdf';
```

That path is only known to your PHP code, which is not visible to users hence they have no idea from where did you read the file they are downloading, just eliminate the guesswork chances though :)

**And Obviously** you have to secure access to this url `https://www.example.com/download.php?aaa=111&bbb=222` otherwise what's the point!

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Yeah, I thought OP was asking something different.

Comment: Yes there is no need to change anything in your code, except moving your files out of web root dir since you said the dir is very important

Comment: @ Hanky Panky -- how to move my files out of web root dir, could you please explain me.

Comment: Do you have a whole server to you or simple hosting setup?

Answer (score 0):

No. The user cannot get the file path. He only get the content outputed by PHP script.

Your can do this and the user only get the "Hello" string. So it's your PHP script's role determining which contents the user can get.

```
<?php
   echo "Hello";
?>
```